# Sonar PDF plugin does not work

Tags: pdf, sonarqube

I have downloaded the Sonar PDF reports plugin and added the widget to the dashboard. I have restarted the Sonar server. I have executed the Sonar analyzer through Ant, but the PDF report cannot be downloaded (the Widget is empty and cannot be seen). The Sonar logs give no indication of PDF generation. Any ideas?

Comment: Does the PDF plugin appear in the list of plugins enabled on startup? I've never enabled this plugin..

Comment: The PDF plugin is displayed in Sonar server under the installed plugins section. I have not configured anything else. I use Ant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Known issue with ANT builds, see [SONARPLUGINS-2314](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONARPLUGINS-2314)

And it looks like there is no immediate solution, they recommend using the commercially supported plugin.....

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/NithinManmohan/PDFQube

still in its infancy, in alpha phase..